# Error installing provider "aws": openpgp: signature made by unknown entity

Tags: aws, openpgp

My provider code in `init.tf` is as below :

```
provider "aws" {
 shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"
 region                  = "us-east-1"
}
```

Terraform version I am using is : `0.11.14`

I am getting error as below while doing `terraform init`:

```
Error installing provider "aws": openpgp: signature made by unknown entity.

Terraform analyses the configuration and state and automatically downloads
plugins for the providers used. However, when attempting to download this
plugin an unexpected error occured.

This may be caused if for some reason Terraform is unable to reach the
plugin repository. The repository may be unreachable if access is blocked
by a firewall.

If automatic installation is not possible or desirable in your environment,
you may alternatively manually install plugins by downloading a suitable
distribution package and placing the plugin's executable file in the
following directory:
    terraform.d/plugins/windows_amd64
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edited `init.tf` as below and it worked for me:

```
provider "aws" {
 shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"
 region                  = "us-east-1"
 version                 = "v2.70.0"
}
```